# Copying the activecell to a cleared textbox and keeping the hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

#### Goals

1. I am trying to make a macro that will copy the `active cell` and paste the contents of that cell to a text box.
2. I also need it to clear the text box before adding the new value, as well as keeping the original hyperlink source.

---

#### Context

I have a large list of items that have hyperlinks to various web pages. What I ultimately want is for a user to search a specific item, using the Ctrl + F function, and the item be copied with its hyperlink into a textbox at the top of the sheet.

Then once a new Item is searched it will clear the textbox and copy the new item into it.

#### Code

All it does is copy the active cell into the text box. I will not clear the box beforehand or copy the hyperlink.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Copy
    Sheet1.TextBox1.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're after the hyperlink address, in the text box then just use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Sheet1.TextBox1 = Target.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Sub
```

If you're after the text, but want the hyperlink to fire when the button (or text) is *pressed* - I'm not sure if either are possible. I guess perhaps you could use the OnAction to cause a hyperlink to fire.. but we'd need more info. Is this an ActiveX Textbox on a sheet?

Comment: Using this code does make it display the hyperlink address. However, I want the link to be able to be clicked after that. I don't want it to Fire the link directly, I want that to be manually done.    I do have the address being copied to an activex textbox.